# Could not create connection to database server - Eclipse MySQL error

Tags: java, android, mysql, eclipse

can you help me? I already did the jdbc build path and my DB savetime exists.

my class:

```
    package br.com.savetime;

    import java.sql.*;

    public class CriarConexao {

    private static Connection con = null;

    public static Connection abrirBanco(){
        Connection con;
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/savetime", "root", "root");
            System.out.println("conectando");
            return con;
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
            System.out.println("driver nao encontrado: " + cnfe.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        catch(SQLException sql){
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + sql.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + sql.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("Erro: " + sql.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("StackTrace: " + sql.getStackTrace());
            return null;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void fecharBDcon(){
        try{
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("erro ao fechar o banco" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

and my error:

```
06-17 03:55:07.139: I/System.out(1367): SQLException: Could not create connection to database server.

06-17 03:55:07.139: I/System.out(1367): SQLState: 08001

06-17 03:55:07.139: I/System.out(1367): Erro: 0

06-17 03:55:07.149: I/System.out(1367): StackTrace: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@41bc1af0
```

Comment: "SQLException: Could not create connection to database" - seems relevant

Comment: Do you have your Driver jar in your classpath?

Comment: Read this: [*Common Problems and Solutions*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-j-usagenotes-troubleshooting.html#qandaitem-25-4-5-3-1-1)

Comment: @RavinderReddy's link is now dead. Try this instead: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-troubleshooting.html

Comment: @Wodin: yes, the one I posted was in MySQL version 5.0. Seems access to documentation on versions 5.0 and earlier is revoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine just provide the `mysql-connector.jar` in classpath.We can find it [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/m/Downloadmysqlconnectorjar.htm) and the code of yours which I tried is :

```
import java.sql.*;

public class ConnectionTest {

private static Connection con = null;

public static Connection abrirBanco(){
    Connection con;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "welcome");
        System.out.println("conectando");
        return con;
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
        System.out.println("driver nao encontrado: " + cnfe.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    catch(SQLException sql){
        System.out.println("SQLException: " + sql.getMessage());
        System.out.println("SQLState: " + sql.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("Erro: " + sql.getErrorCode());
        System.out.println("StackTrace: " + sql.getStackTrace());
        return null;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

public static void fecharBDcon(){
    try{
        con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("erro ao fechar o banco" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
public static void main(String arr[])
{
    System.out.println("Making connection..");
    Connection connection = ConnectionTest.abrirBanco();
    System.out.println("Connection made...");
}
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, my connector was wrong as you told. But now, this error occurs: SQLException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 
I/System.out(1153): ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 
I/System.out(1153): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
I/System.out(1153): STACKTRACE: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
I/System.out(1153):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)

can you help me again?

Comment: It would be very useful if you post the full stacktrace and the failing class

Comment: I think here is better to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24276366/connection-mysql-eclipse-error/24277595#24277595

Answer (score 1):

This is just the mismatch of mysql connector jar file. simply update your jar files with higher version or update your dependency if you are using maven. I updated my dependency in pom.xml with 6.0.6 version and it worked.