# Connection MySQL Eclipse error

Tags: java, android, mysql, eclipse

I'm trying to connect my android project to a database in mysql, it's my code:

```
package br.com.savetime;
```

import java.sql.*;

public class CriarConexao {

```
private static Connection con = null;

public static Connection abrirBanco(){
    Connection con;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/savetime", "root", "root");
        return con;

    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
        System.out.println("driver nao encontrado: " + cnfe.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    catch(SQLException sql){
        System.out.println("SQLException: " + sql.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

public static void fecharBDcon(){
    try{
        con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("erro ao fechar o banco" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

and it's the error:

```
06-18 02:32:57.925: I/System.out(1044): SQLException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 
06-18 02:32:57.925: I/System.out(1044): ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 
06-18 02:32:57.925: I/System.out(1044): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-18 02:32:57.925: I/System.out(1044): STACKTRACE:
06-18 02:32:57.935: I/System.out(1044): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-18 02:32:57.935: I/System.out(1044):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
06-18 02:32:57.935: I/System.out(1044):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
06-18 02:32:57.935: I/System.out(1044):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
06-18 02:32:57.935: I/System.out(1044):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
06-18 02:32:57.935: I/System.out(1044):     at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:133)
06-18 02:32:57.935: I/System.out(1044):     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:280)
06-18 02:32:57.935: I/System.out(1044):     at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1765)
06-18 02:32:57.935: I/System.out(1044):     at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:430)
06-18 02:32:57.935: I/System.out(1044):     at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:268)
```

I'm not conneting to internet so I don't understand why it's occurring this error, could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to open a connection to a database that is not local to your application. The connection you are making is via a network and Android (Honeycomb and forward) does not allow you to make network calls on the UI thread. Use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or some other construct to do your network operations off the main (UI) thread.

**[EDIT]**

Here's an example on how to use AsyncTask to connect to MySQL:

```
private class Connect extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
      String response = "";

      try {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
          // System.out.println("Database connection success"); 

          String result = "Database connection success\n";
          Statement st = con.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from users");
          ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

          while(rs.next()) {
            result += rsmd.getColumnName(1) + ": " + rs.getInt(1) + "\n";
            result += rsmd.getColumnName(2) + ": " + rs.getString(2) + "\n";
            result += rsmd.getColumnName(3) + ": " + rs.getString(3) + "\n";
          }
          tv.setText(result);
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          tv.setText(e.toString());
      }
    return response;   


    }
```

P.S. The code is take from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037730/java-android-asynctask-mysql-connection).

Comment: What can I put as parameter in the connection? private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<??????, Void, Connection>

Comment: @LucasYoshimura I have edited my answer with an example added to it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First is in android localhost refers to its own loop back address if you are trying to connect to mysql on system from emulator use 10.0.0.2 ip to connect to system. For device you have to use usb tethering and both device and system needs to be on same network.
Secondly use ASYNC Task for communication as this will be network call.